# Geoserver Docker - FeatureType layer is not loading in UI

Tags: geoserver, docker

I'm trying to deploy Geoserver 2.22.4 in our docker kubernates setup env.
Geoserver is up and running now, all the options are working except the Feature Type Layer.

But when I click Feature Type layer in 'Layer Preview', 'Layers' below error page is loading and in the logs2, below error is printed:

> [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache
> and retrying: Schema 'TABCAB' does not exist. 29 feb. 07:50:16 DEBUG
> [geoserver.catalog] -  java.io.IOException: Schema 'LAYER_NATIVE_NAME'
> does not exist.
>
> WARN   [geoserver.catalog] - Unable to flush
> 'nl.reggefiber.geoserver:LAYER_NATIVE_NAMEjava.io.IOException: Schema 'LAYER_NATIVE_NAME'
> does not exist.
>
> ERROR  [data.resource] - Grabbing the attribute list failed
> java.io.IOException: Schema 'LAYER_NATIVE_NAME' does not exist.

[image: Feature type layer issue]
[image]
Is this related to any extension library issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the issue.
in OracleJNDI datastore xml file, schema name is not loading from environment.properties file which I placed in the conf directory in my tomcat.
Unfortunately we dont have any option to update the config values in geoserver_data directory when deploying in pod. So I had to prepare the datastore.xml files ready and replace them in geoserver_data directory using an initcontainer configmaps before the pod is initialized.